# How can I add Heat maps in the Web Player?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to find out if it's possible to add a heat map only using Web Player? I know that the Spotfire platform is capable of showing Heat Maps ([link](https://powertools.oncomine.com/SpotfireWeb/Help/GUID-51BAF3CB-E437-4EF7-9E33-18BEB837A087.html)). However, there is no such option when I expand the **Visualisation types** panel:

[image]

has anyone managed to add such a map?

**EDIT**: 
I have noticed that the Spotfire Analyst supports that kind of map but I am trying to do that using the web player:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted TIBCO regarding that and it turns out that this is a feature that is currently not supported on the WebPlayer. There is a feature request on their ideas portal, please upvote it if you have a company TIBCO account [here](https://nam04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ft.yesware.com%2Ftt%2F5c4754834f370d5abbe5cf3f3c4f409eab2639f0%2Ff38808096782c041932e839843771fbf%2Fc455fb0d9cb5da09291ef0cd58c5f9ba%2Fideas.tibco.com%2Fideas%2FTS-I-6343&data=02%7C01%7CGeorgi.Koemdzhiev%40ihsmarkit.com%7C41eb1303d4fb479ff92d08d6f8accc7c%7Cc1156c2fa3bb4fc4ac073eab96da8d10%7C1%7C0%7C636969818396808399&sdata=uwFU1pk3AQ9K56PUOxV3T43edQnE2lDcKtbKs56nR%2FA%3D&reserved=0)